# Complex SQL where clauses - collectively select all but never overlap

Tags: java, sql, set

EDIT: My question was deficient because it was misunderstood. I'm rephrasing it. The original question is below the HR for the curious...

Given several SQL queries that operate on the same data, how can I assert in the type system, object model or test code that each *possible* row is selected by *exactly one* of the queries:

i.e. in this Venn diagram (thank you @Imre_L for the image) what is the best way to *assert* that queries A, B and U do not overlap?

[image]

Note the problem space is all *possible* data and not just the existing dataset.

---

**The original question**

I'm trying to devise a safe and easy to understand mechanism for composing a set of where clauses where the subsets of selected rows never overlap, yet execution of all clauses would select the set of all rows.

For example given a clause (in pseudo SQL) like:

```
... where name like 'Bob%'
and surname not like '%Smith' 
and postcode in (2000, 2010, 2020)
```

and another like

```
... where name in ('Alice', 'Jane')
and postcode < 9000
and married=True
```

and a final query to catch the remainder

```
... where not (name like 'Bob%' and surname not like '%Smith' and postcode in (2000, 2010, 2020))
and not (name in ('Alice', 'Jane') and postcode < 9000 and married=True)
```

How can I assert that each possible row is selected by *exactly* one of the possible queries?

My team is slowly migrating behaviour from one part of the system to another and need, at each stage, to alter the set of statements so that some rows selected by one statement are selected by a different one after the change. The assertion above needs to hold true before and after each change.

I'm looking for a neat solution for Java. Whether it's checked in the type system, or controlled by some creation pattern or even checked during testing it doesn't matter. I'm sure some boffins have some good ideas out there.

Comment: What is 'pseudo-SQL'?  Are you saying that the queries are not in SQL but something else? You want a solution for Java.  Is this a Java in-memory database with a query API?  We're missing a lot of context that would make it possible to understand the question.

Comment: 'Pseudo SQL' is pseudo SQL. It's not a proper noun. It's like pseudo code, but it's SQL. The DB vendor is not relevant, nor whether it is in-memory or not. The essence of the question is about computationally composing complex select clauses; or testing the properties of hand-crafted clauses.

Comment: Well, HOW you compose the queries depends entirely on the capabilities available to you.  Something that is very hard to express in SQL might be easy in a different query language.

Comment: @Synesso are you asking how can this problem be solved, given the toolsets that were available? (e.g. Java and SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is wrong - the question is for all *possible* data**.

I am not sure I understand, but SQL includes `union` and `distinct` so you could check the count for:

1. All queries unioned together
2. All queries unioned together, distinct rows
3. All rows in the table

And they should all be equal.  If you are missing a row completely then 2 will be less than 3;  if you are duplicating a row anywhere then 2 will be less than 1.

The queries for 1 and 2 would be:

```
select count(*) from (
  select ....
  union [distinct]
  select ...
  union [distinct]
  ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to assert for all possible rows - not all existing rows.

Comment: oh.  ok, that's a lot harder...  you need to show that the predicates in your queries together uniquely span the range of possible values (i am just repeating what you said, really).  i have no idea how you would automate that except by using some kind of theorem prover, which is way beyond reasonable.  i'll leave my answer as your comment probably helps clarify for others.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I recognise that this is a difficult problem. If it turns out that it's too difficult to solve practically then I'd except that as an answer too. The best answer I can think of is to use something like scalacheck at test time to insert a large amount of randomised data and then execute assertions using the SQL statements you included above.

Comment: If it is required to assert all possible rows, which means rows that may not exist yet, the solution cannot be purely data-driven. Ouch

Answer (score 1):

This question is more of a math question is set theory. Perhaps venn diagram is here to rescue.

In your example A and B are queries 1,2 and U is the last query.

[image: venn diagram]
learn more about [venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

If you expect better answer you should elaborate more.

Comment: Thanks. Now given three SQL queries, assert that they meet this constraint. That's my question.

Comment: Given the example its easy: A:`name like 'Bob%'` and B:`name in ('Alice', 'Jane')` which makes them not overlap and U is just `not A and not B`

Comment: Yes, but make an executable assertion out of it. i.e. What about my build would fail if I changed it to A:`name like 'Bob%'` and B:`name in ('Alice', 'Jane', 'Bobby')`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in automated testing with a hand-crafted approach.

1. I enumerated the columns involved in the various queries and the distinct where clause conditions for each of these columns.
2. Then I created a cartesian product of these and, in the test setup created an insert statement for each.
3. Finally I executed each DAO method and asserted that the properties in @andrew cooke's answer held true.

I would have preferred a truly automated approach involving a fancy type hierarchy, but we can't always get what we want.